# SQL Server Query All lines for an order in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My schema:

```
Order: OrderNumber, Line, Status 

1, 001, ready

1, 002, ready

1, 003, ready

2, 001, ready

2, 002, packing
```

I cant figure out how to do this query. I want to query all orders that are ready and get all lines for that order as a comma separated list.

What I've been doing is

```
SELECT OrderNumber FROM Order WHERE Status = 'ready'
```

Then doing a for loop over that result set and getting all lines and merging later (Using another programming language (C#).

Is there a way to do this in one query? 
For example to get a result of (1, 001 002 003), (2, 001)

Comment: I tagged with SQL Server.  If this _isn't_ your database, then please edit the tags yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated query with a `FOR XML` option. The `STUFF` removes the leading space used on concatenating the line numbers.

```
SELECT
    R.OrderNumber,
    ReadyLines = STUFF(
        (
            SELECT
                ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), O.Line)
            FROM
                [Order] AS O
            WHERE
                O.OrderNumber = R.OrderNumber AND
                O.Status = 'Ready'
            ORDER BY
                O.Line
            FOR XML
                PATH ('')
        ),
        1,1, '')
FROM
    [Order] AS R
WHERE
    R.Status = 'Ready'
GROUP BY
    R.OrderNumber
```

If on SQL Server 2017, you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) aggregate function:

```
SELECT
    R.OrderNumber,
    ReadyLines = STRING_AGG(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), R.Line), ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY R.Line ASC)
FROM
    [Order] AS R
WHERE
    R.Status = 'Ready'
GROUP BY
    R.OrderNumber
```